# How do I add a new SSD to an old mainboard?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata

My knowledge of this stuff is out of date, and judging from the research in the Qs here, I've missed a lot.

I have an older Gigabyte mobo with PCIe3 slots, but not M.2-capable ones. One PCIEx8 slot is free. I also have a free SATA3 connection.

I know what performance I can expect from a SATA connection, but I'm unclear whether there's any advantage to using an adapter in one of the PCIe slots to mount a new NVMe SSD. I understand (I think) that I can't get the full performance I'd get from a native M.2 slot. But can I still do better that straight SATA using such a configuration?

This won't be a boot drive, just storage. It will replace a RAID10 set of 4 5400rpm drives that use a H/W RAID controller.

Comment: If not for a boot device then the speed difference is a moot point. Choose the cheaper option, a SATA 2.5" SSD is perfectly fine and doesn't require any adapter.

Comment: Most disk controllers address M.2 slots by assigning them sata lanes, so the connection to the northbridge is the same either way.

Comment: @JimMack `I can't get the full performance I'd get from a native M.2 slot` This might not be true. If the x8 slot gets no less than 4 lanes of bandwidth, it will not be inferior than an M.2 slot of the same PCIe version. The adaption is purely physical (i.e. no bridging / translation is involved).

Comment: @JimMack though note that old mobo might have have firmware that supports booting from an PCIe/NVMe drive.

Comment: @TomYan - the listed transfer rate of a SATA drive like Samsung 870 is ~550MB/s, where the rate for an M.2/NVMe drive is ~3500, and from what you say, PCIe8 can be similar. Yet an answer here says there should be little real-world difference. Can you help explain this? (Storage drive, not boot drive)

Comment: What the answer said has nothing to do with M.2 PCIe slot vs "full-size" PCIe slot, but the fact that how much one can "feel" when the secondary (as opposed to primary, i.e. RAM) storage is much faster depends on the actual usage and various factors. For example, if you are copying from a USB 5Gbps drive, which is slower than a SATA drive, then you won't get any advantage with an NVMe drive as the destination.

Comment: For the record, M.2 to full size PCIe adapter is pretty much dirt cheap in where I live (like 3-4 USD, shipping included), and NVMe drive (at least those PCIe 3.0 ones that are of the same "grade") is not at all more expensive (actually sometimes cheaper) than SATA drives.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a huge operating difference between SATA and NVMe.  I have a ThinkCentre desktop with straight SATA Samsung SSD drives and an i5 CPU.  I have a ThinkPad laptop with NVMe Samsung SSD drive and an 17 CPU. Both have 16 GB of memory. The X1 is faster but maybe 10% faster.

So I would stick with the straight SATA adapter (to economize).

You will notice a very large speed improvement in data access and operations over 5,400 rpm drives for sure. I got a big improvement from 7,200 rpm drives in the desktop.

Comment: Good to know. So what accounts for the claims that NVMe drives outperform SATA 6Gb by "up to 7 times"? I see drive specs that claim a max xfer speed of 540 MB/s for SATA 3 and 3500 MB/s for NVMe / M.2. In the case I'm considering, is it the adapting to a standard PCIex8 that loses this advantage?

Comment: The claims may need to be modified in a real world situation. My desktop (SATA) is ready to go about 15 seconds longer than my laptop (NVMe) - base startup 60 to 70 seconds.

Comment: There is a huge difference in drive performance, but how that translates to overall system performance is another matter. Often when you max out one component in a system you end up moving the bottlenecks around.

Comment: At then end of the day it is practical application and use that counts because that is what we see